Tailwind colour token naming conventions
I need to implement design colour tokens in Tailwind.
The tokens are named semantically, with some examples being:

Text/Main/BodyPrimary
Surface/Background/Secondary
Border/Button/PrimaryOutline

I have added these tokens to Tailwind using the extend.colors object in the tailwind.config.js file, with the token paths above being implemented as follows:
extend: {
  colors: {
    text: {
      main: {
        bodyPrimary: #ffffff,
      },
    },
  },
}

However, the tokens I have lead to clunky implementations in practice due to Tailwind requiring colours to be pre-fixed with the property that they are being applied to.
For example, the token above would have to be applied as follows:
<p className="text-text-main-bodyPrimary">
  Hello
</p>

Is there a way to add tokens of this format to Tailwind that would bypass the duplication of the property they are being applied to (e.g. text-text..., border-border...)? Or, will I need to re-write the tokens without using words such as text, bg, border etc?

Classes for color (text-<color>), border-color (border-<color>), etc. have their own object key "group" as well as inheriting values from colors. This means you could map your token prefixes to them, like:



Token Namespace
Tailwind Configuration Key
Class name prefix




Text
textColor
text


Surface
backgroundColor
bg


Border
borderColor
border





tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        background: {
          // Surface/Background/Secondary
          secondary: 'darkblue',
        },
      },
      borderColor: {
        button: {
          // Border/Button/PrimaryOutline
          primaryOutline: 'lime',
        },
      },
      textColor: {
        main: {
          // Text/Main/BodyPrimary
          bodyPrimary: 'lightpink',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="bg-background-secondary border border-button-primaryOutline text-main-bodyPrimary">
  Foo
</div>



